# What's with the "Afx" in StdAfx.h?

Tags: .net, mfc, fxcop, stdafx.h

I'm just curious what Afx stands for. And what about Fx in FxCop?

Comment: +1: Just wanted to ask the same. Since I came from "Linux world" I was always curious, about what this file contains. It was always something different. Over the years of experience, the existence of this file in a project simply give me a signal: "Attention, bad code!"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Framework_eXtensions):

> One interesting quirk of MFC is the
>   use of "Afx" as the prefix for many
>   functions, macros and the standard
>   precompiled header name "stdafx.h".
>   During early development what became
>   MFC was called "Application Framework
>   Extensions" and abbreviated "Afx". The
>   name Microsoft Foundation Classes
>   (MFC) was adopted too late in the
>   release cycle to change these
>   references.

[The old Stingray MFC FAQ](http://cs.sookmyung.ac.kr/class/00891/C++/mfc-faq/) (no longer found on their website, link is to ancient version):

> In the beginning, Microsoft created
>   a group called the AFX group
>   (stands for (A)pplication
>   (F)ramework(X)).

[...]

> The AFX group was actually
>   responsible for two things: the MFC
>   library    and the IDE's support for
>   MFC (namely, the resource editor and
>   the    wizards). The AFX name was
>   dropped in April 1994, and the group's
>   members simply became part of smaller
>   teams within the Visual C++    group.
>   One of those smaller teams is today's
>   MFC team.

Answer (score 9):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdafx.h

"The AFX in stdafx.h stands for Application Framework eXtensions. AFX was the original abbreviation for the Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC)."

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, gstercken's [answer](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?342987-What-does-afx-in-MFC-stand-for&p=1163220#post1163220) in codeguru.com mentions about **"x"** in Afx.

(emphasis mine)

> The first version of MFC has started being developed in 1989 by a group at Microsoft known as the application framework technology development goup - known as the AFX group.
> According to a widespread belief, AFX stands for "Application Framework eXtension". According to George Shepherd and Scot Wingo, however, the legend goes like this: **"AF" didn't sound so great by itself, to they added "X" to get a three-letter acronym. The X doesn't really mean anything.**
>
> It's significance? Well, you will encounter Afx as a prefix for some functions and constants in MFC. It's significance is purely historical - **it shows us how they called the framework internally, before it shipped under the name MFC 1.0 in 1992.**

Answer (score 1):

In FxCop its Framework.

Comment: That explains the F, what about X?

Comment: X? You don't want to know.

Comment: Didn't you know? Including X in product name increases sales by 20%

Comment: sometimes it's nice to see these funny comments even in SO :)